# ScrollView inside ViewPager inside NestedScrollView not scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I have an activity which contains a Nested ScrollView in it. Inside this NestedScrollView there is a ViewPager. Each Page has a view which contains a ScrollView. This innermost scrollview is not scrolling at all. 
How can I enable the scrolling behaviour in this innermost ScrollView

This is the xml of Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is xml of view pager

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="800dp" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I don't get why you have a NestedScrollView wrapping your ViewPager? Since you have ScrollView on each view I don't think that's needed. And also would be nice to have some code.

Comment: Because my view pager is a part of Activity and activity contains many small different kind of views and I need them to scroll as well along with view pager content

Comment: found solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add    `android:fillViewport="true"` in your `NestedScrollView`. I hope the problem will be solved

Comment: Please share your xml. I want to see actually what you are doing

Comment: shared xml. Please take a look

Comment: use root layout as  androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
If we are using androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView and androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager i.e. androidx version of NestedScrollView and ViewPager and your view pager is not. scrolling inside NestedScrollView, Make. the root layout as ConstraintLayout, It will work

Answer (score 0):

The scrollview will only scroll if there is content inside and it takes up all the width in the view. Then you will be able to scroll

Comment: It contains all the content for scrolling

Comment: Whats the layout height and width of the parent containers? Its possible they have collapsed from no content.

Answer (score 0):

> It will be much easier if you add xml file here
>   Also,
>   Try to add Scroll View in Activity and Nested Scroll View in the Views hold by viewPager
>   Also try to add

```
fillViewPorty = true
```

in your top scroll view

Comment: Please share XML

Comment: shared please take a look

Comment: @vs.thaakur is there any special reason to use constraintLayout?

Comment: Yes, my original view heirarchy is pretty complex. This is a simplified case

Comment: Try to use <ScrollView> tag after constrainLayout tag.... instead of <Nested>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200998/discussion-between-humxa-moghal-and-vs-thaakur).